# Python not recalling variable (pycharm)

Tags: python, input, positioning, pycharm

Does Anyone Know whats wrong with calling the input at the beginning of the code where i ask someone to input the number they wish to proceed to for some reason it doesn't want to do it

```
__author__ = 'kowalczk'
print ("Welcome to my Program")
print ("It has many functions. If you wish to:")
print ("- Interact with the PC - Press 1")
print ("- Add, Subtract, Multiply Or Divide two numbers - Press 2")
print ("- Put any number of words in alphabetical order - Press 3")
print ("- Display the exact date and time - Press 4")
print ("- Count to any number you like - Press 5")
print ("- Cycle through the whole program - Press 6")
Command = float(input())


if Command == "1":
    negative = "angry","depressed","confused","helpless","irritated","lousy","upset","incapable","frustrated","resentful","disgusting","distrustful","distressed","inflamed","abominable","misgiving","woeful","provoked","terrible","lost","pathetic","incensed","in despair","unsure","tragic","infuriated","sulky","uneasy","in a stew","cross","bad","pessimistic","dominated","worked up","a sense of loss","tense","boiling","fuming","indignant","indifferent","afraid","hurt","sad","insensitive","fearful","crushed","tearful","dull","terrified","tormented","sorrowful","nonchalant","suspicious","deprived","pained","neutral","anxious","pained","grief","reserved","alarmed","tortured","anguish","weary","panic","dejected","desolate","bored","nervous","rejected","desperate","preoccupied","scared","injured","pessimistic","cold","worried","offended","unhappy","disinterested","frightened","afflicted","lonely","lifeless","timid","aching","grieved","shaky","victimized","mournful","restless","heartbroken","dismayed","doubtful","agonized","threatened","appalled","cowardly","humiliated","quaking","wronged","menaced","alienated","wary"
    positive = "open","happy","alive","good","understanding","great","playful","calm","confident","gay","courageous","peaceful","reliable","joyous","energetic","at ease","easy","lucky","liberated","comfortable","amazed","fortunate","optimistic","pleased","free","delighted","provocative","encouraged","sympathetic","overjoyed","impulsive","clever","interested","gleeful","free","surprised","satisfied","thankful","frisky","content","receptive","important","animated","quiet","accepting","festive","spirited","certain","kind","ecstatic","thrilled","relaxed","satisfied","wonderful","serene","glad","free and easy","cheerful","bright","sunny","blessed","merry","reassured","elated","jubilant","love","interested","positive","strong","loving","concerned","eager","impulsive","considerate","affected","keen","free","affectionate","fascinated","earnest","sure","sensitive","intrigued","intent","certain","tender","absorbed","anxious","rebellious","devoted","inquisitive","inspired","unique","attracted","nosy","determined","dynamic","passionate","snoopy","excited","tenacious","admiration","engrossed","enthusiastic","hardy","warm","curious","bold","secure","touched","brave","sympathy","daring","close","challenged","loved","optimistic","comforted","re-enforced","drawn toward","confident","hopeful"
    print ("Please tell me your name")
    name = input()
    print ("So", name, ",how are you feeling today?")
    feeling = input().lower()
    while feeling is "":
        print ("How are you feeling today?")
    reason = input()
    if feeling in negative:
        print ("Why is that", name)
    reason = input()
    while reason is "":
        print ("Why is that?")
    reason = input()
    elif feeling in positive:
    print ("That's great", name)


elif Command == "2":
    print ("In this section of my program i will calculate anything that you need me to, press enter to continue")
    input()

    print ("If you wish to add press 1, subtract press 2, multiply press 3 or divide press 4. If you wish to exit press enter")
    operation = input()

if operation == "1":
    print ("Input first number")
    n1 = float(input())
    print ("Input second number")
    n2 = float(input())
    print (n1, "add", n2, "is", n1 + n2)

if operation == "2":
    print ("Input first number")
    n1 = float(input())
    print ("Input second number")
    n2 = float(input())
    print (n1, "takeaway", n2, "is", n1 - n2)

if operation == "3":
    print ("Input first number")
    n1 = float(input())
    print ("Input second number")
    n2 = float(input())
    print (n1, "times by", n2, "is", n1 * n2)

if operation == "4":
    print ("Input first number")
    n1 = float(input())
    print ("Input second number")
    n2 = float(input())
    print (n1, "divided by", n2, "is", n1 / n2)


elif Command == "3":
print ("Now i will put some words in order for you. please tell me how much words you wish me to put in order for you")
amount = int(input())
#create a list
mywords = list()

#use a simple counter
counter = 0

# loop through
while counter < amount:
   #get input from user
   word = input('Enter word: ')
   #add the word to the list
   mywords.append(word)
   #add one to the counter
   counter = counter + 1

#get creative with sort etc.
print (sorted(mywords))


elif Command == "4":
print ("This is the exact date and time. In the form yyyy-mm-dd and hh-mm-ss-ms")
print("Press enter to show")
input()
#This code prints date and time originally in the form yyyy-mm-dd
#hh:mm:ss.ssssss
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print (now)
print("This is the date in the form dd-mm-yyyy")
print("Press enter to show")
input()
#This shows date in the format dd-mm-yyyy
print (now.day, -  now.month, -  now.year)


elif Command == "5":
print ("Now i will count to any number you wish me to count to")
print("Press enter to continue")
input()
print ("Tell me what number you wish me to count to")
CountTo = float(input())
x = 0
while x < CountTo:
    x = x + 1
    print (x)
```

Im also getting an error regarding the 
    if feeling in positive:
for some reason i cant get that to work asswell

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your `input()` return to float , in the line -

```
Command = float(input())
```

And then you are checking this `Command` against strings, in lines like -

```
if Command == "1":
```

They will not match, since strings would never be equal to `float` . You do not need to do the float convertsion -

```
Command = input()
```

---

Also, you should fix the indentation, indentation is very important in Python, it is used to define blocks.

Each separate block should be indented at a particular level from the previous block , the recommended indentation is 4 spaces.

---

For the second issue said in the comments -

> line 29 elif feeling in positive: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The issue is in lines -

```
if feeling in negative:
    print ("Why is that", name)
reason = input()
while reason is "":
    print ("Why is that?")
reason = input()
elif feeling in positive:
```

This is occuring because you have an `elif` part without an if part. Most probably, you want to indent the `while` part inside the `if` block, if so *indent* it.

Comment: think it is better to user raw_input

Comment: only if OP is using `Python 2.x` , there is only `input()` in python 3.

Comment: im getting this error right now elif feeling in positive:

Before i wrote the first 10 lines of code it was working

Its on line 29

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by - `negative = "angry","depressed", ...
positive = "open","happy", ...` , what are the dots?

Comment: <I can specify location of file since its work pc >line 29                                                  elif feeling in positive:                                                                                                            ^                                                                                                                                        SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The dots mean basically that the positive and negative feelings are continued. If you look in the code now i edited it to show the whole line

Comment: Like I said in the answer, indentation is important, that is indented wrongly, check again at your code why , you should understand.

Comment: i cant see a fault in the indentation

Comment: And again, if what you added now is the actual code, there is still tons and tons of indentation issue, go through the code line by line and you will understand.